# vb.net server connection overloads

Tags: sql, vb.net, smo

I'm trying to run this code, but it displays the error "overload resolution failed".

```
Conn = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)    
Dim serverConn As New Server(New ServerConnection(Conn))
```

Here is the full error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Sub New(serverInstance As String)': Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'String'.
'Public Sub New(sqlConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)': Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.
'Public Sub New(sci As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo)': Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage a MS SQL Server, you want `SqlConnection`, not a generic `OleDbConnection`.

Either replace `OleDbConnection` with `SqlConnection`, or pass the `ConnectionString` right into `New Server()` without instantiating an explicit connection first.